# Is there any out of the box solution to cut diagonally a mesh with multiple cuts?

Tags: modeling, mesh, tools

It is my third day using blender and well, the first time I have asked a question in a stackoverflow-like forum, so bear with me.

I have added a round cube to my scene which I have turned into a sort of platform, now here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

I would like to cut the mesh in a diagonal fashion with all cuts ideally having the same distance in between each other and that the resulting meshes also have rounded edges.

So essentially, I would like to end up with a platform that is made out of rounded edge "beams".

Is there any way to do this with the features that blender comes with or would I have to resort to some external solution? Either way I would appreciate any kind of guidance, even if it's a complex solution with many steps.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a plane to the scene, rotated 90 so it stands up straight, and 45 so that it is rotated on the diagonal
[image]
go to your modifiers stack and add add a solidify and an array modifier,

[image]

adjust the values of these two modifiers adding thickness to the solidify and offsetting the planes in the right axis

[image]

Now to your round cube add a boolean modifier set to difference with the plane selected as the cutting object.

[image]

Hide the planes, adjust the settings and positions of the objects to your liking and you are done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this will do just fine. On an additional note: Is there any way to make the resulting "beams" singular meshes?

Comment: @konamiscc duplicate the round cube (just in case you change your mind). Go to the modifiers and apply the boolean, then select all in edit mode.  Press "p" and choose "By Loose Parts", it will save all the pieces as separate objects.